# How to wait for _.each loop with ajax call to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js

Take the following example:

```
_.each(arrayOfVals, function (val) {
   $.when(getAjaxCall('foo',{val:val}))
   .then(function (callResponse) {
      _.each(callResponse, function (rep) {
         console.log(rep);
      });
});
```

I then want to call some code after the entirety of that code is complete. How can I do this?

Comment: Use Promise.all API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a $.Deferred object to listen to when everything is done and called the resolve when I've gone through the entire list.

```
deferred = $.Deferred
i = 0;

_.each(arrayOfVals, function (val) {
   $.when(getAjaxCall('foo',{val:val}))
   .then(function (callResponse) {
      _.each(callResponse, function (rep) {
         i += 1;
         console.log(rep);
         if (i == callResponse.length) {
            deferred.resolve();
         }
      });
});

deferred.done(function() {
   console.log('everything done!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple arguments to `$.when` and its deferred will resolve when they all complete. If you have an array, use `.apply`.

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfVals.map(val => getAjaxCall('foo', {val}))
  .then(responses => responses.map(resp => console.log(resp));
```